# How do I make Tools Options show up in GIMP 2.8?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP 2.8.

How do I make Tools Options window show up? E.g. I select a Flood Fill tool, and I would like to change Threshold.

Answer (score 13):

In menu go to :

`Windows`>`Dockable Dialogs`> Click on `Tool Options`

You can select any other needed window in `Dockable Dialogs`.

Answer (score 5):

If you double-click on an icon in the Toolbox (e.g. Flood Fill), the Tool Options dialog will appear. This is much faster than using the menus.

Comment: Note that it might no appear where it was (under the toolbox), but where the layers are ...

Answer (score 4):

right click -- > windows --> Recently closed Docks --> tools options , channels ...

[image]

Comment: There's nothing in the `Recently closed Docks` for me.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov ok you could find in the answer above. But if you open and loose it again this should help you

Answer (score 1):

[Screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avZM9.jpg)
Nickolai I think I've figured it out. See attached screengrab: there are three little dots at bottom of tool-options box. Drag the downwards to reveal rest of contents.
On Gimp 2.10 on Windows using a 32" 4k monitor, and gimp is almost unuseable due to tiny icons.