# GIMP: How to show the tool options in GIMP 2.10

Tags: gimp

The options of any tool do not seem to appear. I have tried all the [answers in this other similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396377/how-do-i-make-tools-options-show-up-in-gimp-2-8), but they do not work.

[image: Current situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue. Apparently, the Tool Option was appearing as a separate GUI window and it had appeared in another monitor screen. Hence I could not locate them initially. I had to toggle Windows --> Single Window Mode twice, and shift the Tool Option to the same display column to get this final result [image: final result]

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. The current implementation of the grouped tools is rather counter intuitive.

Hovering the tool should normally display a tooltip showing the different tools. However, this already does not appear to work for you. Perhaps, you have "Show tooltips" switched off in Preferences - Interface - Help system. The confusing aspect is that you cannot interact with that tooltip to select a different tool.

To change a tool, you need to click and hold the mouse button. Now, a menu, looking quite similar as the popup though, appears. You can move the mouse button (while holding the mouse button down) over a different tool. Releasing the mouse button selects the different tool

That is the way it works by default. It can be changed in the Preferences, Interface, Toolbox. For example, the menu mode "Show on hover" may be more intuitive: then, instead of the tooltip, the menu is shown when you hover over. If needed, you can directly change the tool. Otherwise, you just click to select the tool. There is not need to hold the mouse button.

Many tools can be selected typing a letter, or Shift+letter, on the keyboard. That hotkey is mentioned next to the tool in the popup or menu.

Comment: I agree with you and hope the GIMP developers can display the tools in a more intuitive manner as a default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and deleting the ~/.config/GIMP solved it

Comment: Though this solves it, but changing it through preferences may be a better option.